# Command working in cmd prompt, but not in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run this command:

```
mshta javascript:alert("Thanks for taking a look at my question! :D");close();
```

It runs fine in the cmd prompt, but when placed in a batch file, I get this error:

```
close() was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: What are you expecting `close()` to do?  Is it an HTA command?  Sorry, don't know much about HTA.

Comment: @PaulHicks It closes the javascript window that lingers after the message. Run the command without the `close();` to see what I mean.

Comment: Your code in a bat file works fine. On my system

Comment: @sachadee Weird, it doesn't work in mine. Paul Hicks' answer fixes it though!

Comment: Yes it's the good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the batch script, the semi-colon is terminating the mshta command, instead of the HTA command like you want it to.  You'll have to quote the HTA command, or provide a script to mshta.exe.

I think that this should work:

```
mshta "javascript:alert('Thanks for taking a look at my question! :D');close();"
```

Comment: @sachadee strange, the inverse is happening to me. What system do you have? I really need my code to be portable.